# Two forms on one page, can you prevent refresh when submitting one of two forms?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Java/Springboot/Thymeleaf app has a page with multiple forms. One form contains a modal that pops up when you click a button, so you can attach files. When you hit submit to attach the file, it gets saved to a file on the server, but refreshes the original form and I lose my form inputs. Any way to prevent the default so it doesn't refresh causing loss of data from other form (that hasn't been submitted yet), and still submit to get the file uploaded to my server?

HTML:

```html
    <div id="modal" class="modal" data-izimodal-title="Upload a Document">
       <div id="newRequiredDocForm">
           <form enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="directBind"  method="post" th:object="${document}">
              <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right"><label class="modalLabel">Type:</label></div>
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right">
                   <label class="modalLabel">File:</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7">
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="document" multiple="multiple" style="margin-right:-20px;"/>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <br/><br/>
              <div style="text-align: right;"><input type="button" id="attachTheDoc" class="btn btn-docModal" value="Submit"/></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/directBind_ajax", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Document docSend(@ModelAttribute("document") Document document, Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        document.setStorage(storageService.store(file));
        model.addAttribute("newDocument", document);
        return document;
    }
```

Ajax Javascript:

```html
$('#attachTheDoc').click(function(){
  var data = $('#file').val();
  console.log($('#file').val());
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      url: "/directBind_ajax",
      success: function(data){
          alert("Your files have been saved");
      },
      error: function(){
          alert("Error - File not uploaded");
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you can find your reponse her : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31552397/4373948

Comment: @TinyOS thanks! this is helpful... still a little stuck though, because I want to send a file to a server, not save it, getting an error when trying to post. Will edit my original post to show what I have. Anyone know why the ajax post isn't working for me?