# Ajax call used to upload a file to folder on the server returning 403 error

Tags: java, ajax, apache, spring-boot

So after days of research, I am still stuck on this modal situation...
I have a two forms on one page, but one is in a modal. Seems that the only way to submit the modal (which just lets users upload a file to save on server when submitted) without the page refreshing (and loosing data from other form), is to use a javascript ajax call. I keep getting a 403 error in the browser when I do this... not sure why or how to fix it since I am not getting any real error notices. Is it my ajax post or controller? Not sure... please help!

I was able to upload the file to the folder in java/spring-boot but I was loosing form data because modal submit would refresh page, so I don't think this is a server issue. And if I use on('submit') instead of onClick, it sends the file to the storage folder, but refreshes the page. Why isn't my onclick function working?

I've been basing my situation off of this: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546424/spring-mvc-4-and-thymeleaf-prevent-page-refresh/31552397#31552397)

HTML:

```html
    <div id="modal" class="modal" data-izimodal-title="Upload a Document">
       <div id="newRequiredDocForm">
           <form enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="directBind"  method="post" th:object="${document}">
              <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right"><label class="modalLabel">Type:</label></div>
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right">
                   <label class="modalLabel">File:</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7">
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="document" multiple="multiple" style="margin-right:-20px;"/>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <br/><br/>
              <div style="text-align: right;"><input type="button" id="attachTheDoc" class="btn btn-docModal" value="Submit"/></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/directBind_ajax", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Document docSend(@ModelAttribute("document") Document document, Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        document.setStorage(storageService.store(file));
        model.addAttribute("newDocument", document);
        return document;
    }
```

Ajax javascript:

```html
$('#attachTheDoc').click(function(){
  var data = $('#file').val();
  console.log($('#file').val());
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      url: "/directBind_ajax",
      success: function(data){
          alert("Your files have been saved");
      },
      error: function(){
          alert("Error - File not uploaded");
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: The workflow seems odd. Not saying you are wrong, but why have a modal to upload a file before sending the form? Normally you'd select the file in the form and it gets uploaded together with the rest of the form when submitting.

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel I am open to other ideas, but what needs to happen is the file needs to be attached (temporarily saved somewhere) so when the overall form is submitted, attachment gets emailed along with other form input values.